# SQL update to database not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to update my database but it is not working.

I first tried this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\QuizDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();

string command = "UPDATE QuizTable SET ques1= @ques1VAL WHERE ID=@IDVAL";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@command, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ques1VAL", ques1TextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDVAL", IDTextBox.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

It doesn't throw an error but it doesn't update the database. When I tried the next code, only integers are updated and not strings.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\QuizDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();

string command = "UPDATE QuizTable " +
                 "SET ques1=" + ques1TextBox.Text +
                 " WHERE ID=" + IDTextBox.Text;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@command, con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I prefer code to be secure against SQL injection is possible please.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when I see someone do `AttachDbFilename` they really should not be using it. Do you only ever plan on having more than one instance of the program connecting to a database? (multiple users on IIS count as a single instance) If the answer is `yes` to you should not be using `AttachDbFilename`

Comment: It didn't work with @IDVAL.

Comment: I checked the wrong database. It does work with @IDVAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case you are missing `@` at where condition so, it should be like-

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\QuizDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();
string command = "UPDATE QuizTable SET ques1= @ques1VAL WHERE ID=@IDVAL";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@command, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ques1VAL", ques1TextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDVAL", IDTextBox.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

In your second case you pass the .text but not use proper string quotations. It should be like -

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\QuizDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
con.Open();
string command = "UPDATE QuizTable " +
               "SET ques1='" + ques1TextBox.Text +
               "' WHERE ID='" + IDTextBox.Text+"'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@command, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Why not this time?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the "@" for the IDVAL paramer:

```
string command = "UPDATE QuizTable SET ques1= @ques1VAL WHERE ID = @IDVAL";
```

Comment: The OP just updated his question and included the `@`